# CSS percentage of screen with position:absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little "floating" menu type thing to the left of a profile displaying some info and it looks good, however i used a different pc before and it was overlapping the main page body (due to screen resolution).

So this is the original CSS(with CSS3 fancy stuff stripped out):

```
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #73a7f0;
width: 200px;
left:10px;
top: 160px;
padding: 5px 14px;
border-radius: 4px;
```

and this is what i am trying to do, the line that has changed is:

```
width: 10%;
```

Any ideas how it can look the same depending on screens?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `width: 10%;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diodeus' answer is true if the container has static positioning. If the container has a width set, even a percentage width, and the container has a position other than `static` (the default), the child will use that as the context for its percentage width.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/USJnN/

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. When a width is specified for a block element, the width is **relative to its container**. Without a fixed-sized container, a percentage doesn't really have a size context other than the browser window, which is variable.

Using a width in pixels is what you need in this situation.

Comment: So i just have to assume a min monitor value?

Comment: You can have a "min-width:" No idea what "monitor" value means.