# Why does container size depend on absolute-positioned child?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am attempting to build a Skype-like interface with two video boxes:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9ER2/20/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body
            {
                background-color: #000000;
                height: 100%;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }

            body
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            #videoContainer
            {
                position: relative;
                max-width: 800px;
            }

            #bigRemote
            {
                /* Shrink if necessary */
                max-width: 100%;
                max-height: 100%;
            }
            #smallLocal
            {
                position: absolute;
                height: 30%;
                width: 30%;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="videoContainer">
            <video id="bigRemote" controls preload="none" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
                <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source id="webm" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source id="ogv" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
            </video>
            <video id="smallLocal" controls preload="none" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
                <source id="mp4" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source id="webm" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source id="ogv" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
            </video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The big box (`bigRemote`) represents the remote video stream. The little box (`smallLocal`), represents the local video stream.

I've run into a problem: as you shrink the result window vertically, `smallLocal` box will drift away from the bottom-right corner of `bigRemote`. The reason is that `smallLocal` is bound to the bottom-right corner of `videoContainer` and the latter does not shrink as `bigRemote` does.

I was under the impression that `position: absolute` children are ignored when determining the layout/size of a container. **How do I make `videoContainer` fit around `bigRemote` as the latter shrinks?** (I believe doing so will indirectly cause `smallLocal` to stick to the bottom-right corner of `bigRemote`.)

- I want the video to grow/shrink with its container so you cannot remove max-width/height or setting explicit size on `videoContainer`.
- I want the video to maintain its aspect ratio, so having it match the size of `videoContainer` won't do either.

Comment: Please follow guidelines for posting jsfiddle links: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: You'd need to position the bigger video also absolutely and set the bottom and right to zero, however you'd also need to set some widths for it to be displayed properly to begin with this way.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587868/css-percentage-of-screen-with-positionabsolute

Comment: `videoContainer` does in fact shrink as `bigRemote` does. The problem here is that `bigRemoteVideo` doesn't take up the entire space provided by `videoContainer`. To  fix this, try setting 100% height on `bigRemoteVideo` and giving `videoContainer` an explicit height. You can see a demonstration of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6AntG/).

Comment: @Lowkase, I don't get your point. This isn't a link-only question. The link is mostly a visual aid.

Comment: @j08691, The video needs to grow/shrink with the page, so your proposal won't work.

Comment: @Asad, updated the question to indicate why your solution won't work.

Comment: a) Most of the comments here are yours. b) An answer will only be posted when someone has an actual solution to the problem. I posted my fiddle as a comment since it only explained that the container is in fact resizing. That helps diagnose the problem more accurately, but does not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle **demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2qYe/show) [(edit)](http://jsfiddle.net/J2qYe)

Assuming the **requirements** are:

- Keep original video proportions
- Keep video at original size when possible
- Resize the video to fit the window
- Small video at bottom right corner
- Small video always is 30% the width of the big one
- No scrollbars

The **solution** I found that works in (at least) Chrome 26.0, Firefox 19, IE9, IE10:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap"><video class="big" controls preload="none" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>
</video><video class="small" controls preload="none" poster="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/poster.png">
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

.wrap{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.big{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.small{
    max-width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Surprisingly `display: inline` is the only display type that worked as desired on the wrapper. `inline-block` didn't work in Firefox and had some issues in Chrome.

`font-size` and `line-height` are set to avoid some `inline` spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the max and min width/height attributes and set the video containers to block. Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but it looks close:

http://jsfiddle.net/q9ER2/5/

```
html, body
{
    background-color:lime;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container
{
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#bigRemote
{
}

#videoContainer
{
    position: relative;
}

#bigRemoteVideo
{
    /* Shrink if necessary */
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
}
#smallLocalVideo
{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I need the video to grow/shrink with the container, so this solution won't do.

Comment: The video grows and shrinks in the jsfiddle I provided.  Unless I am missing something here all you need to do is adjust the size of the window when looking at that jsfiddle.

Comment: Your solution sort of works. When I shrink the window horizontally, the video shrinks to fit; however, when I shrink it vertically I get scroll-bars and the video does not resize.

Comment: Just did some reading.  Looks like the HTML5 video tag forces an aspect ration on itself.  There are some work-arounds it looks like:http://wsmithdesign.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/changing-the-aspect-ratio-of-html5-video/.  In the end, I think my jsfiddle is correct, its just that the video tag takes over and forces an aspect ratio.

Comment: But I *want* the video tag to maintain its aspect ratio... so we still need to find a way to fix your answer.